# Is it possible to parse xml server side with meteor?

Tags: xml, api, meteor

I want to write a simple app that interfaces with an external api. Unforunately, the api I am working with doesn't support json.

I was wondering if it is possible to parse xml serverside, so I don't have to just pass xml to the client and use jquery to parse it.

The api I am trying to use is the [Pivotal Tracker Api](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api)

Comment: i would install an xml parser node-module then, in a Meteor method, use `Meteor.http` (in synchronous mode) to make the calls to your API

Comment: or you could make your own package to parse XML

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install npm modules in Meteor. Go to .meteor/local/build/server and install the module there. It'll go into node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

See the more up-to-date method of installing node modules into meteor:
[2013 Meteor NPM Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583438/2013-meteor-npm-packages)