# How to structure a large meteor.js application?

Tags: javascript, meteor, requirejs

So right now I my project is structured so that my server side code lives in a server folder.

I have broken up my javascript into multiple files and was previously using require.js. 
Right now, I've tried using

```
Npm.require
```

and

```
__meteor_bootstrap__.require
```

to get the 'exports'object of the different files, but that is not working.

In other words, how do I properly use require.js with Meteor? Or is there some better way of breaking up large javascript files in Meteor?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you look at building your app entirely out of smart packages. Since 0.6.0, you can have local packages under packages/

As best practice, any app-specific package folders would be namespace-prefixed (example: myapp-billing)

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to break some of your project into modules that can be released on separate release cycles and perhaps shared with other projects, then you are on the right track by making them into require.js style  modules (if you just want to break one big .js into multiple, then do as user728291 suggests).

If you do create multiple require.js style modules, you should completely break those modules out of your Meteor project and put them into separate directories, e.g.

workspace/
    /my-meteor-project/
      ...project contents...
    /reusable-module-1/
      package.json
      reusable-module-1.js
    /reusable-module-2
      package.json
      reusable-module-2.js

Then, install these Npm modules locally using `npm link`, or share them with the world by using `npm publish`.  Then, here is a discussion of best practices for [including Npm modules in Meteor applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583438/2013-meteor-npm-packages/17600107#17600107)

Comment: For meteor, you should not break your modules into npm-style modules, but instead into meteor smart packages.

Comment: Right -- unless your modules are generic modules that you want to use outside of meteor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make a package.  [Here](https://github.com/avital/meteor-xml2js-npm-demo) is an example of Npm.require() being used in a package.

Also packages already exist for many common js libraries so check [atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/) and maybe you will not need to write your own package.

You can also just place .js files in a directory structure like [this](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files) without needing to use Npm.require and packages which may be easiest if you already have code working in one .js file on the server.