# Using Meteor Node-CSV-NPM

Tags: csv, meteor, npm

I am starting a project to import a CSV, transform it, and re-export back to a new CSV.  Step one has been to get Node CSV up and running.

I have installed the node-csv-npm package to my Meteor app directory and confirmed in terminal that I am "already using" node-csv-npm.

Yet, for some reason, when I run the basic example to test my set-up (see code), I get back "Uncaught ReferenceError: csv is not defined"

Simple Coffee Code I am using:

```
if Meteor.isClient
    console.log "client started."
    csv().from.string("#Welcome\n\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\"\n\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"", comment: "#").to.array (data) ->
        console.log data
        # [ [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ], [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] ]

if Meteor.isServer
    console.log "Server Started"
```

Thanks for any insight!

---

As requested in comments, posting entire app code (.coffee file)

```
if Meteor.isClient
    console.log "Client Started"

if Meteor.isServer
    console.log "Server Started"
    csv().from.string("#Welcome\n\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\"\n\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"", comment: "#").to.array (data) ->
        console.log data
        # [ [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ], [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] ]
```

Comment: Are you using the `npm` package as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583438/2013-meteor-npm-packages)?

Comment: Have you actually added the .js file on the client using the `api.add_files` call? Clients do not have access to node, so the script must be added directly.

Comment: @cuberto: I moved the code to the server, but still no go.  In the console I see "ReferenceError: csv is not defined".

Comment: @DavidWeldon, I am using: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/node-csv-npm

Comment: @Cuberto: No require required as I am using: https://github.com/Dsyko/meteor-node-csv.  I posted the full code above, but it's essentially my initial post as I am just trying to get csv to work right now.  Also of note, I can see the "node-csv-npm" folder in my packages directory, so it's there.

Comment: Oh, try using `CSV()` instead of `csv()`.

Comment: @Cuberto - YES!  That was it.  Thank you very much for sticking with me on this one.  Super helpful!!