# Npm Packages and Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

I am really struggling with Meteor and the NPM package [node-linkedin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-linkedin).

I understand how NPM integration is supposed to work. I added NPM using Meteorite and node-linkedin to packages.js. I am then calling the NPM package through Meteor.require().

Here is my server/linkedin.js file:

```
function Linkedin(accessToken) {
  this.linkedin = Meteor.require('node-linkedin')('api', 'secret', 'callback');
  this.accessToken = accessToken;
  this.linkedin.init(this.accessToken);
}

Linkedin.prototype.company = function() {
  var self = this;
  var data = Meteor.sync(function(done) {
    self.linkedin.companies.company('162479', function(err, res) {
      done(null, res);
    });
  });
  return data.result;
}

Meteor.methods({
  getCompanyInfo: function () {
    var linkedin = new Linkedin(Meteor.user().services.linkedin.accessToken);
    var data = linkedin.company();
    return data;
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, it does not work when I call getCompanyInfo()... I get the following error: "Cannot call method 'company' of undefined".

Linkedin Auth works fine (thanks to accounts-linkedin). But I also need to connect to Linkedin API.

I had previously followed [this article](http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/facebook-graph-api-meteor-js) to play with FB Graph API in Meteor. Everything was fine.

Maybe the problem comes from Metheor.require(). I am wondering what I am supposed to do with the second set of parameters in Metheor.require(). Should I add these npm packages to packages.json as well? Does Method.require() handle this second set of parameters correctly?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you found answer to your question ? I am facing the exact same problem

Comment: See [2013 Meteor NPM Packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583438/2013-meteor-npm-packages).